# Touchpad not working on a Toshiba R700-18Q with Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, touchpad, toshiba

A few days ago I installed Ubuntu on this old Toshiba laptop. Everything was working fine (including an external mouse), except for the touchpad, which does nothing.

On Ubuntu Software > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers, it searches for a few seconds but then says "no additional drivers available".

On Settings > Devices > Mouse & Touchpad there's also nothing helpful.

I looked for some other solutions online, but nothing worked, so I just reinstalled Ubuntu and came to you for help.

Thank you in advance.

xinput output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2+USB Mouse                            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ 2SF001: TOSHIBA Web Camera                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Raw Set 2 keyboard                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Alright, it's done!

Comment: The touchpad is detected. Maybe it is disabled by Fn+Fx button, etc.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried (with and without the external mouse connected), it's not that. FN is working, because FN+F10 toggles the numpad on and off.